# How to convert date format into milliseconds in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have date in postgresql in format "17/12/2011".

How can i convert it into milliseconds using select clause of postgreql ?

Currently i am just executing select clause as

```
select tableDate,tableSales 
from table_name
```

I want to have something like when I select tableDate it should be converted into milliseconds using some postgresql functions.

```
tableDate DATE
tableSales Numeric
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`extract(epoch from ...)` will return the number of seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00` so all you need to do is to multiply that by 1000:

```
select extract(epoch from tableDate) * 1000, tableSales 
from table_name
```

More details in the manual:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT