# EXTRACT epoch ends in a syntax error - Postgres

Tags: postgresql, datetime, extract

I had the need, to calculate the difference of two timestamp in miliseconds. This is the approach i made:

```
-- calculate the differenz of two timestamps in milliseconds
DO $$
  declare _t1          timestamp;
  declare _t2          timestamp;
  declare _extract_ms  double precision;
BEGIN
  _t1 = now();
  _t2 = (_t1 - INTERVAL '1 HOUR');
  -- _extract_ms = EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP _t1::timestamp) - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP _t2::timestamp); -- UNCOMMENT 01
  -- _extract_ms = EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM date_trunc('milliseconds', _t1)) - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM date_trunc('milliseconds', _t2)); -- UNCOMMENT 02

  RAISE NOTICE '_t1=%  _t2=%  _extract_ms=%', _t1, _t2, _extract_ms;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

0 - Executing the code as shown before, results in the following output:

`HINT:  _t1=2022-02-22 14:14:59.627456  _t2=2022-02-22 13:14:59.627456  _extract_ms=<NULL>`

1 - Now uncomment the line marked with "UNCOMMENT 01" and execute the code again ends with:

```
ERROR: Syntax error at »_t1«
LINE 9:    _extract_ms = EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP _t1::timestamp...
```

2 - Now comment line marked with "UNCOMMENT 01" again and uncomment line marked with "UNCOMMENT 02" and execute it again:

`HINT:  _t1=2022-02-22 14:28:43.161478  _t2=2022-02-22 13:28:43.161478  _extract_ms=3600`

This is the expected result!

If I simply run
`select EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP now());`
I get

```
ERROR: Syntax error at »now«
LINE 1: select EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP now());
```

I stumpled over [pgplsql: SELECT EXTRACT(...) functioniert nicht](https://www.tutorials.de/threads/pgplsql-select-extract-functioniert-nicht.353421/) and thought this is the solution - not for me.

So, can anyone explain me why variant 1 and even the simply select-statement fails?
Thanks in advance.

Answers read:
[How to convert date format into milliseconds in postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35860994/how-to-convert-date-format-into-milliseconds-in-postgresql),
[Calculate difference between dates - Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46204351/calculate-difference-between-dates-postgres)

Comment: `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM _t1)` - the `timestamp` keyword is not part of the `extract` syntax and the cast is not needed

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. `TIMESTAMP` is part of the syntax if you are using timestamp string e.g. `select extract(epoch from timestamp '02/22/2022 7:50'); 1645516200`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: yes, but it belongs to the constant, not to the defined parameters of `extract()`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I know that but it is not obvious if one looks at the docs [Extract](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) or the linked example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this:

```
select extract(epoch from timestamp '02/22/2022 7:50'); 
 date_part  
------------
1645516200

select extract(epoch from '02/22/2022 7:50'::timestamp);
 date_part  
------------
 1645516200

select EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP now());
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "now"
LINE 1: select EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP now());

select timestamp now();
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: select timestamp now();

select EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM now());
     date_part     
-------------------
 1645545952.426751
```

The `TIMESTAMP` is a `CAST` of the timestamp string to a timestamp type. The same thing is done by the `'02/22/2022 7:50'::timestamp`. In either case the cast is looking for a string. The `now()` and  `_t1/ _t12` in your case are already timestamp types so you get the error. So if you are using a value that is a `timestamp/timestamptz/date` type already don't use `TIMESTAMP` to cast it.

Comment: Thank you for your explaination. I agree with you, one doesn't see at a glance in the docs. I tried a lot of different syntax, but always with the keyword `TIMESTMAP`. Anyway, you helped me and again thank you.